# Covariance in inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, covariance

I have a super class SheetBuilder and many sub classes that inherit this class.
The super class has an abstract method that all the classes inherit.

```
protected abstract void printResults(String abc);
```

Now I want to overload the same method with a different parameter but I need to do this only for one sub class. So I changed the abstract method as below,

```
protected abstract void printResults(Object abc);
```

This way I can just implement my sub class with whatever object type I want to receive as,

Sub class impl:

```
protected void printResults(int abc) {
//
}
```

Is this the correct standard or this there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: your method should be as much specific as possible, are the subclasses really printing results with any kind of objects?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you created an instance of your subclass, but referred to it as an instance of the superclass, and then called `foo.printResults(new Object())`? That clearly can't call the `printResults(int)` method...

Comment: ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ : Yes. I need to pass different type of objects to each sub class.

Comment: Jon Skeet : foo.printResults(new Object()) this will never happen as this is hard coded to either be String or int.

Comment: int is not even an object reference but a primitive so there is nothing to gain in declaring the parent abstract method parameter as Object. Even when printResult(int) and printResult(X) (where X is any class) share the name, they are effectively two different/independent methods; of course they should share semantics as they share the same name... that is the "soul" of overloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected abstract void printResults(Object abc);
```

> Now I want to overload the same method with a different parameter but
>   I need to do this only for one sub class. So I changed the abstract
>   method as below,
>   Is this the correct standard or this there any other way to achieve
>   this?

No, Object is too wide. From the client side if you want to program by interface you will have to call this `printResults(Object abc);`.
And you can put any type of instance inside.

Besides I think you mix overriding and overloading. This is overloading and not overriding because overriding cannot change the declared arguments types :

```
class Base{ 
  protected abstract void printResults(Object abc);
}
...  
class BaseImpl{
  protected void printResults(String abc) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Here BaseImpl has two method printResults().

If you add @Override in the BaseImpl method, the compilation will fail as it is not the same method:

```
class Base{ 
  protected abstract void printResults(Object abc);
}
...  
class BaseImpl{
@Override
  protected void printResults(String abc) {
    ...
  }
}
```

To answer to your question, if `void printResults(String abc)` is specific to a single class, add this method only in this class.
In this case, you could not program by interface to invoke this method as this method is specific to a class.
But if the method is specific, it is acceptable and even sometimes desirable.

Another way to cope with your problem would be to create a base class with a generic method which the parameter may have a distinct type according to the concrete class, use generics :

```
class Base <T>{ 
  protected abstract void printResults(T abc);
}
...  

class BaseStringImpl<String>{
@Override
  protected void printResults(String abc) {
   ...
  }
}

...
class BaseIntegerImpl<Integer>{
@Override
  protected void printResults(Integer abc) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: "Besides I think you mix overriding and overloading." - I have never mentioned override in my question : )

Comment: @mani_nz  I know but the code you write looks like overriding :)

Comment: Thanks Davidxxx!! This helped me explore more options : ) Cheers!!